# getDownloadUrl() cannot resolve method

Tags: android, firebase

Нужно, чтобы пользователь мог загрузить изображение в Firebase.

```
final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

Хотела использовать этот код, но getDownloadUrl() устарел и не работает. Как его можно заменить?
Весь код ниже

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){
        Uri ImageUri = data.getData();
        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(this);
    }

    if(requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if(requestCode == RESULT_OK){
            loadingBar.setTitle("Profile Image");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please,wait, while we updating your profile image");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");
            filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Profile Image stored successfully to Firebase storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        UsersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                            Intent selfIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(selfIntent);
                                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Profile Image stored to Firebase Database Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error Occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Occured: Image can not be cropped. Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В Firebase Storage API версии 16.0.1 метод getDownloadUrl(), использующий объект taskSnapshot, был изменен. Попробуйте так:

```
task.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

или так:

```
task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

или так:

```
Task<Uri> t = task.getStorage().getDownloadUrl(); //вариант 1
Task<Uri> t = task.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl(); //вариант 2
t.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
       @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
              String photoLink = uri.toString();
        }
});
```